# How do I get my two tables to align beside each other?

Tags: html, css, html-table, rows

I can't get my two tables to align next to each other. The second blue box (of smaller boxes) keeps sitting below the first box. I've tried using "display: inline-block" and "float: left" on every single element, but nothing happens. Please help?

```css
#zero-data {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

#table-12 tr {
  display: inline-block;
}

.data-1234 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
  text-align: center;
}

#table-34 tr {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Problem.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- big table -->
  <table id="zero-table">
    <tr id="zero-row">
      <td id="zero-data">0</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!-- tables 1 & 2 -->
  <table id="table-12">
    <tr id="row-1">
      <td class="data-1234">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-2">
      <td class="data-1234">2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!-- tables 3 & 4 -->
  <table id="table-34">
    <tr id="row-3">
      <td class="data-1234">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-4">
      <td class="data-1234">4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried ghost columns? Place it between the tables. The ghost columns will be read by outlook.

Comment: @Syfer I'm not sure what ghost columns are, but I'll look that up. Thanks for letting me know about it!

Comment: You can set them to inline tables - https://jsfiddle.net/bf8h1h78/

Comment: @Pangloss That works great too, thanks for the help! Wow I am really bad at this stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
}

#zero-table,
#table-12,
#table-34 {
  float: left;
}

#zero-data {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.data-1234 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table id="zero-table">
    <tr id="zero-row">
      <td id="zero-data">0</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="table-12">
    <tr id="row-1">
      <td class="data-1234">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-2">
      <td class="data-1234">2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <table id="table-34">
    <tr id="row-3">
      <td class="data-1234">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-4">
      <td class="data-1234">4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that's it, Thanks a million! I must've forgotten to use the wrapper. Otherwise, thank you!

Comment: Yup Just did, appreciate it!

Comment: I just forgot to remove it when doing initial test for the result

Comment: @Pangloss Then I am really not sure what I did wrong because I applied a "float: left" to every element but nothing happened. But rafarlp answered that lol. I'm still new to html/css, so it gets confusing lol

Comment: That you should ask the person who posted the answer, but the demo above works.

Answer (score 1):

Give ghost columns a try. Place it between each of the tables.

```
<!-- your table -->
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> 
</td> 
<td width="150" align="left" valign="top"> 
<![endif]-->
<!-- your table -->
```

Once you place it in the tables should start aligning properly. Change the width of the TD to whatever it's supposed to be in your code. Let me know you go.

Comment: It's fine, Carl Jan resolved the issue. But I'll try to use this method sometime. Thanks for informing me about it!

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question. I thought this was for emails.

Comment: Oh no I was using the boxes to store photos

Answer (score 1):

No need to add Float to every element. Since you want the second and third tables to appear beside the first table, you just add Float to that first table:

```
#zero-table { float: left; }
```

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dj9rjf30/)

Comment: Ah I see, it gets very confusing. Thanks for clearing that up!