# two columns with background-image in outlook

Tags: outlook, html-email

I want to create two tables that are next to each other in outlook, and they should be placed in a table with an background image.

I know that one can create a background image in an outlook email like this:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;">
<v:fill type="frame" src="image.jpg" color="#F4C046" />
<v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->
    <table width="100%" align="center"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
             <!-- place content here -->
            </td> 
        </tr>
     </table>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
</v:textbox>
</v:rect>
<![endif]-->
```

I also know that one can create a two column table design like this:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="full-width" width="295" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; color: #000; line-height: 24px;">
            hi
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="full-width" width="295" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <img class="img-full" src="image_1.jpg" alt="img" width="295" height="250">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</table>
```

However, when I put the above table into `<!-- place content here -->` then the background is working, but the two tables are not next to each other, but below each other.

Is it possible to get both working in outlook?

I don't want to create a single table with two columns, because it should be responsive in addition. When I have two tables I can simply set the width of the tables to 100% with media queries.

I also tried using floats on the two tables as explained in [How do I get my two tables to align beside each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42776633/how-do-i-get-my-two-tables-to-align-beside-each-other), but this is also ignored in Outlook.

Comment: The chosen answer from the above link is using float, not all email clients read floats properly.

Comment: @Syfer float is also not working inside the background-image workaround

Comment: Yes that's why I recommended ghost columns. You can control the look with table columns and rows.

Comment: @Syfer ghost columns are no option for me, because I need responsiveness in 2019, as mentioned in my question.

Comment: You can use ghost columns and using CSS you can target those and make it responsive. `I need responsiveness in 2019` doesnt say in the description above?

Comment: @syfer how can you make the columns responsive? Setting the width of the td to 100% with media query doe snot seem to work either? To the responsiveness - I did not say it word for word like that in the post, but I said: `I don't want to create a single table with two columns, because it should be responsive in addition. When I have two tables I can simply set the width of the tables to 100% with media queries.`

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Use ghost tables. The reason your tables are stacking in Outlook is because you aren't adhering to the Outlook rule of 20px gap between tables. Stupid rule, but it's a known issue.
2. Reduce the width of your tables to adhere the to 20px gap Outlook rule. So make both inner tables, 290px. This way, you'll avoid needing Ghost tables. But that impacts the width available to the content inside of those tables.

Honestly, Ghost tables are your best option. I use them religiously, in almost every build. These will only render in Outlook, so you won't have issues with responsiveness on mobile.

Comment: Never heard of the outlook gap. But even if I make the parent table to a width of 2000px they are still not next to each other, but stacked instead.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those stupid issues and was one of the reasons people researched, experimented and found the Ghost Table fix. Okay then, well the background code is playing silly buggers, which can happen even when you do everything correct. You're best to wrap both tables in ghost tables and see what happens then. I would be very surprised if that doesn't fix it. If it doesn't, that would point to a larger issue in the code base that needs to be identified and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your code and made changes to it.

- A new table added to encase your two columns.
- Ghost column added for Outlook support
- New table added to encase the VML and two column block
- Added width and height to your VML

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    .full-width{width:100% !important}
}
```

```html
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full-width">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;width:600px;height:250px;">
<v:fill type="frame" src="image.jpg" color="#F4C046" />
<v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->
        
        <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="full-width">
          <tr>
            <td><table class="full-width" width="300" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; color: #000; line-height: 24px;"> hi </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              
              <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> </td><td align="left" valign="top" width="300"> <![endif]-->
              
              <table class="full-width" width="300" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center"><img class="img-full" src="image_1.jpg" alt="img" width="295" height="250"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
</v:textbox>
</v:rect>
<![endif]--></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I havent tested your VML as it has a relative path

Once you have tested the above code, let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score -2):

What Outlook is actually doing, if you look close, is creating a "text box" and anything that goes in there is made into an image. So while this method gives you the illusion of a background image in outlook, it's really just that, an illusion. You'd be better off making an image and using that. This is probably why your tables are getting all messed. I discourage you from using this method for anything other than very simple background images.

Comment: So your saying its not possible to hae a background image and two responsive columns?

Comment: Not true. This can be achieved with the use of ghost tables, as mentioned in my answer. Ghost tables are a way to hand hold Outlook into rendering your code as close to what you expect as possible.